# Como enviar formulário sem dar refresh na página?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Eu fiz um código que depois de selecionar o `radio button` ele envia para uma página mas ele esta dando `refresh` e não quero isso quero q ele não de `refresh` na página mas continue enviando e quero também que quando enviar ele apareça um `alert` estou tentando implementar isto do `alert` e do `refresh` e até agora nada. Segue meu codigo abaixo:

jQuery:

```
$(".radioo").click(function(){
        $("#rating").submit();

           $.alert({
            title: 'Atenção',
            content: 'Todos os campos sao obrigatorios!',
            });
            return;
        });
```

a parte do formulário esta assim:

```
<form method="post" action="rating.php" id="rating">
<div class="estrelas">
  <input type="radio" id="cm_star-empty" class="radioo" name="fb" value="" checked/>
  <label for="cm_star-1"><i class="fa"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioo" id="cm_star-1" name="fb" value="1"/>
  <label for="cm_star-2"><i class="fa"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioo" id="cm_star-2" name="fb" value="2"/>
  <label for="cm_star-3"><i class="fa"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioo" id="cm_star-3" name="fb" value="3"/>
  <label for="cm_star-4"><i class="fa"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioo" id="cm_star-4" name="fb" value="4"/>
  <label for="cm_star-5"><i class="fa"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioo" id="cm_star-5" name="fb" value="5"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Como fazer as implementações nesse código de ele enviar o `form` para a página rating sem dar `refresh` e assim que enviar aparecer uma mensagem do tipo 
suas implementações foram salvas com sucesso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usando AJAX:

```
$(".radioo").click(function() {
  var option = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "rating.php",
    data: { poll_option : option },
    success: function(response) {
      alert('Dados enviados.');
    }
  });
});
```

Adaptado de uma pergunta semelhante no [SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814369/getting-radio-button-value-and-sending-through-ajax-to-php)

Comment: obrigado cara funciono perfeito